# Maximizing a convex function under constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Consider the following non-convex problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \text{maximize}
& & f(X) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & f(X)\le b\\
&&& A_kX = c_k, \ k=1,..,n\\
&&& X \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Where $f(X)$ is a convex function and $A_kX=c_k$ are linear constraints.
In addition, we know that there is unique solution $X^*$ such that $f(X^*)=b$. In other words, if we indeed succeed in maximizing $f(X)$ under these constraints then we have found the unique solution $X^*$.

My questions are:

1) Can this problem be in principle be solved? by solved I mean that we are guranteeed to find the solution $X^*$, that is, maximizing $f(X)$ under the given constraints.

2) What algorithm is reccomended for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, but it is non-convex so in practice hard. Trivial reformulation is to simply define $X$ as $RR^T$, and now you have a standard non-convex program which you can throw your favorite global non-convex solver on. Alternatively, upper bound the objective with a simple concave function, solve the relaxation, and then proceed with a spatial branch-and-bound strategy. Not saying these are prefered or good approaches, just answering the question whether it is possible in principle.